# How to install FFMPEG in DSX?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, data-science-experience, librosa

I want to process `.mp3` files in DSX for Music Information Retrieval. I am using `librosa` library in python for this purpose. But I am unable to load `.mp3` files due to absence of `ffmpeg`. Is there a way to install `ffmpeg` in DSX or any other walk-around to load `.mp3` files in DSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the libraries that need sudo permissions cannot be installed on Spark service associated with notebook on DSX by user.

You can only install libraries with `--user` flag in pip.

Only IBM Spark service team can install this libraries which need sudo permissions.

Please raise a request/idea here to get this library installed:-
https://ibmwatsondataplatform.ideas.aha.io/?category=6441922592725708622

Thanks,
Charles